# Liquibase stopped being able to see some files on classpath after Liquibase version upgrade

Tags: liquibase

I'm trying to setup testcontainer to use as backupdb, and I'd like it to start it from shell, initializing it with Liquibase. Everything already worked for me, I ran Liquibase update from cli, and it went through just fine, finished current task with all OK.

Now I'm trying to do it once again, using the same command from bash history — well I suppose — and for some reason, main Liquibase changeLogFile is found within fat.jar, but files it references are now searched for in local directory instead of fat.jar.

What could be wrong/why is this happening?

Command:

```
java -Xmx256m -jar fat.jar --logLevel=debug \
--contexts=contextsHere --labels='...' --defaultSchemaName=X \
--url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XEPDB1 \
--driver="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" --username=X --password=X \
--changeLogFile=dbs/X/install-X.xml \
update \
-Dliquibase.contexts=contextsHere -Djava.io.tmpdir=. \
-Ddb.appUser=X -Ddatabase.defaultSchemaName=X
```

within fine logs, for every changeset file:

```
[2023-11-02 21:02:56] FINE [liquibase.resource] Path dbs/X/X/increments/X.xml in <current directory> does not exist (liquibase.resource.DirectoryResourceAccessor (<current directory>))
```

why is it not searching within fat jar? All files are present there. The changelog references other file like:

```
<include file="dbs/X/v1.0/X.xml"/>
```

the file IS in the fat.jar. Liquibase can see the main entry one `dbs/X/install-X.xml` but not the ones referenced from there, which are in same location.

---

### Update

Surprisingly enough it's caused by Liquibase version upgrade. I raised version to 4.24.0 to be able to use labels. If I go back to 4.9.1, run the same command, all is found all works and my Liquibase fails on first unappliable changeset, which wasn't indeed filtered out by label. Surprisingly even more, now I can change the version back to 4.24.0 and it will continue to the end without a hiccup. But if I try to ran it with 4.24.0 against fresh db, Liquibase won't find classpath resources. I understand, that these two shall be unrelated and how crazy this sound. But I just tested it again from scratch.

Quick workaround for this is not to use labels & new version of Liquibase, and filter unwanted changesets using contexts. But it's desirable to get newest Liquibase version working, and as far as I understand, command provided in original question should do. And it should be able to find resources on classpath regardless of current DB state.

Comment: running into the same issue. do you have any updates?

Comment: sorry, no. I created 'same' mwe , but that one worked. No idea where is difference. I reported it, but it seems they dont understand issue. Fix wont be soon. I just stopped using labels in affected project.